# Adding a folder from local machine to github

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and github. I am trying to add a folder from my local machine to github

I committed the changes and when I am trying to push to github I am facing challenges.

Here's the list of commands I tried but getting errors.

```
JAYASHREE ~ $ cd "C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Desktop\Data Analyst Nanodegree"
JAYASHREE (master *) Data Analyst Nanodegree $ git push origin remote
error: src refspec remote does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
JAYASHREE (master *) Data Analyst Nanodegree $ git push origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
JAYASHREE (master *) Data Analyst Nanodegree $ git push  remote master
fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
JAYASHREE (master *) Data Analyst Nanodegree $ git log
commit 81bbf5e5f72ef4ec5dc08cd989a61e13899c8c7b
Author: Jayashree <saishree999@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 22 07:07:16 2017 +0530

    added git commands file and deleted games.js files

commit 1b16729fdc52ad0fc394ae67e47f86d8ed363c1c
Author: Jayashree <saishree999@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun May 21 17:30:58 2017 +0530

    Data Analyst folder
JAYASHREE (master *) Data Analyst Nanodegree $ git remote add DAND https://github.com/jayashreesridhar
JAYASHREE (master *) Data Analyst Nanodegree $ git push remote master
fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
JAYASHREE (master *) Data Analyst Nanodegree $ git push origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What command should I use to push my changes to github?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check `origin` is set by running by executing below command

```
git remote -v
```

This shows you all of the push / fetch remotes for the project.Verify remote name / address, It will show something similar to below one

```
$git remote -v
DAND https://github.com/jayashreesridhar/repository-name.git (fetch)
```

Seems like `DAND` is set instead of `origin` so below execution will fail

```
$git push origin master
```

Instead you need to use like this

```
   $git push DAND master
```

To change the remote's URL,  remove the old remote, and then add the correct one.

```
$git remote remove DAND
```

You can then add in the proper remote using

```
$git remote add origin https://github.com/jayashreesridhar/repository-name.git
```

Then try below `push` command it should work

```
   $git push origin master
```

Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository depending on the remote name either `origin` or `DAND` use it as below

```
git remote set-url (origin | DAND) https://github.com/jayashreesridhar/repository-name.git
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of this command

```
git remote add DAND https://github.com/jayashreesridhar
```

You've named your remote `DAND` so

```
git push DAND master
```

But that doesn't look like the repository url, but rather your profile.

It should probably be something like

```
 git remote set-url DAND https://github.com/jayashreesridhar/repository-name.git
```

Then push again

```
git push DAND master
```

Or just name your remote `origin` per the standard convention

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/jayashreesridhar/repository-name.git
```

Then push normally

```
git push origin master
```

You can check what remotes you've already got with

```
git remote -v
```