# How to push a project folder from IDEA to Github repository

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I have a clean Github repository. If I initiate a local Git repo and do Initital commit and then do the following:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/kirill-ch/my-repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

then I get there my project files - the **/scr/** folder and **pom.xml**.

I would like to **have a folder in my repository** in which I can hold my project so that I can commit different projects in different folders in the future.

How can I do these from the command line or from IDEA?

I have seen the question: [Adding a folder from local machine to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103581/adding-a-folder-from-local-machine-to-github)
however I don't understand what there going on.

Comment: IntelliJ has a Git client that's excellent.  You just have to set up your project to connect to the GitHub repo and pull down the code.  You can then use the client to commit and push.

Comment: Just an addition to an accepted answer: You create a root folder - let's say "git-projects". Then place there file ".gitignore" with your exceptions to avoid unnecessary files in your Github repo. Then place your project folder (or several projects) and make all git commands in root folder. So you will get necessary folders in your Github repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. If the folder you want is not yet being tracked by git

Just place your folder with the data in your repository root directory and then add the changes and commit.

1. Move the files to a new directory in your repository root directory.
2. If you run `git status` you should now see a list of all the files you have added to your repository.
3. In the command line, locate to your repository root directory and then run `git add .`.
4. Commit the changes: `git commit -m "Your commit message"`.
5. Push your changes: `git push`.

Note that git does not know anything about directories/folders, so you cannot add an empty directory in your git repository, git won't find it.

### 2. The folder/files are already being tracked by git

You can move your `/src/` and `pom.xml` to another directory say `test` by running the following command (assuming those files are already being tracked by git):

```
git mv src test
git mv pom.xml test
```

These will allow git know that you have moved your files to another directory so you now just need to commit and push the changes to the remote repo.

Please note that you cannot have a single local git repo with different multiple remote repos for different directories in your local repo. What you can do instead, is to have multiple local git repos with each having their corresponding remote repos and just house all of them under a single directory on your system (not git directory, just a normal directory).

Comment: Yes. This is working. Thanks a lot. One more issue - at this case I receive in my repository all Maven and Idea files that I don't want to get there. Should I manually delete them from my local directory and then push? Or there some other methods? When I use IDEA I can manage this by .gitignore file.

Comment: Great. Yes, I can move src/ and pom.xml to "test" folder. Now I don't get how I can push only this "test" folder to my Github repo...?

Comment: `.gitignore` is your way to go. You specify in there files or directories you want to avoid. Here you can find a list of good templates to start with: https://github.com/github/gitignore. If those files have been tracked in the past by git, you need to explicitly delete them now, but they will be ignored next time.

Comment: A git repo is an entire thing. You can not tell git to have different remote repos for different directories. If you need multiple remote repos for multiple projects, then create a local repo for each project, add remote repos for each and then put all of them in a single folder. Then you can manage different projects individually.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.